# Using a pattern when implementing a natvis visualizer

Tags: xml, visual-studio, natvis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

    <Type Name="BBB">
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[base]">(P_BBB)((X*)this-&gt;member)</Item>
    </Expand>
    </Type>

  <Type Name="AAA">
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[base]">(P_AAA)((X*)this-&gt;member)</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>

</AutoVisualizer>
```

How to avoid duplication when writing visualizers for AAA, BBB, ...? I suspect I need to use a regular expression and a group in it, but I don’t know the exact syntax. X is not important here.

Comment: Can you please extend your sample to show what exactly is duplicated and what you want to write only once!?

Comment: You can avoid duplication only by using `<AlternativeType Name="AAA"/>`. Another case is create visualaser for `X`. What is `P_BBB` and `P_AAA`?